# send form information to python module

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using the tornado framework and I want to send information users input into a form to another python module. Currently in my python module I have a tornado class which gets the form input data, as such:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('main.html')

    def post(self):
        event = self.get_argument('event')
        print event
```

I now want to send this data (event) to another module as an arg.

The more complete code is:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.options
from pymongo import Connection
from bson import json_util
import json
import os.path

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.render('main.html')

    def post(self):
        event = self.get_argument('event')
        return event



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'Server is alive.....'
    app = tornado.web.Application(
    handlers=[(r'/', MainHandler)],                           
    #(r'/ws', WSHandler)],
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    debug=True)

    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

So  I have a variable(event) in a class function which I want to use in another module. This is where I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

By module do you mean something you have access locally or something on an external service??

if it is local it is simple as importing the correct module and function

```
from yourpackage.yourmodule import yourfunction
yourfunction(event)
```

If you want to send data via http to an external service tornado offers an async http client for this. http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html

I misunderstood your question `MainHandler` is meant to be run as a server using:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This would then expose your methods through a request to localhost:8888.  So if you went to localhost:8888 in your browser `main.html` template would be rendered.

Then if you made a post request to `localhost:8888` with an `event` parameter it would be echoed out for you to see

Comment: It's my own module locally. So, could I do "from tornadoPY import MainHandler" and then do MainHandler(event)? I'm bit confused because MainHandler is a class.

Comment: We are as well confused about what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: In main.html the user enters a keyword into the form....MainHandler then gets this data. I now want to send this to another module which will use this for processing. I know we can import the module but I'm confused about using the function as its in a class.

Comment: Then it seems you need to create an object of this class somewhere and call a method on it. Show us more of your code, otherwise nobody can help you.